# More than 50,000 records load ng-repeat in dropdown list in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-repeat

I displayed 100 records using ng-repeat in dropdown list faster.

but,

I have to fetch more than 50,000 records using ng-repeat in dropdown list,

While fetching application is hanged and not responding needs to close a project.

How to display faster in dropdown list using ng-repeat?

Comment: Nobody can consume that many items at one time. Use some filtering

Answer (score 0):

No one have a time to scroll and select 50,000 records in dropdown and select. Instead use the dropdown with custom search option, it will give your users to more interactivity and performance in dropdown.

Initially render upto maximum of 500 records and display them in dropdown. Allow user to search through the drop down, when user enters the search value, based on value get those values from database and append it to dropdown.

Also you can achieve the above scenario using the following plugin.

https://github.com/axel-zarate/js-custom-select

You can use this plugin to create dropdown with custom search and make you own ajax function to get datas from server.

Hope this will help you.